# Are there any ways to run an arbitrary main method via Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I realize when I use IntelliJ IDEA CE and make a Gradle-Java project.

When I run a Class.main(), say Hoge.main(), 
the run window shows like

```
0:15:03 PM: Executing task 'Hoge.main()'...
```

and in gradle tasks list

```
:Hoge.main()
```

[image]

like this (the bottom line).

How can I do this in a terminal (not using IDEA)? If possible, it may be like this? (I know about https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html, which is not flexible for my purpose)

```
gradle run Java Hoge
```

Is this only in IDEA?
I saw some ideas using the application plugin but I could not find very simple way like above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the gradle wrapper is for. If you have the wrapper (in *[ProjectDir]/gradle/wrapper* folder), then you can use Gradle without an IDE.

A) In Windows, execute the `gradlew.bat` script;

B) In Unix, execute the `gradlew` script.

In your case, you would type in the terminal following:
`gradlew run` or `./gradlew run`.

P.S.
If you want to have several "run" tasks, you need to create them like so:

```
task runHoge(type: JavaExec,group: 'application'){
    classpath(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath)
    // set the main class name here
    setMain('package.Hoge')
}
```

Comment: but how can I choose a specific class to run?

Comment: You can make customized instances of `JavaExec` tasks for that - see P.S. in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe IDEA emulates this way doesnt it?
Thanks again.